# Problems by printing svg. Print Window will just select the left part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, svg, printing

I'm trying to print an SVG chart by using JavaSript. The print window shows just the left part of the HTML page and each time I have to move my chart to the left. How can I print everyting what I see on my window? This is what I have:

```
function print() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("tree");
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var svg = serializer.serializeToString(elem);
    console.log(svg);
    svg = '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/treeStyle.css"/>' + '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/indexStyle.css"/>' + svg;
    var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0;top=0;width=800;height=600;toolbar=0;scrollbars=0;status=0;');
    printWin.document.write(svg);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
}
```